# How can I access array element by index using MongoDB 3.0?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to know how I can access the elements of an array in mongo (version 3.0) by position, just as I would with $arrayElemAt in the newer versions.

UPDATED: I want to achieve the same of this example using mongodb 3.0:

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean querying or reading? You can always use the old prop.[position].attr sintax.

Comment: I mean querying

Comment: please be more specific. It is not cleat what do you want to query. I would suggest you to give a sample of the collection, its attributes and then what would be the expected result from a query.

Comment: Hi @Cleriston, I've updated the original question, please look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Just use `{ $slice: [ skip, limit ] }` in order to achieve `$arrayElemAt` whete *skip* is a number and *limit* too.

Comment: I can not find a way to use it within a $project clause

Comment: You are right, `$slice` operator is not available in mongodb 3.0. May be you want take a look in [map-reduce operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/).

Comment: Note that MongoDB 3.0 is very old and not supported anymore. If possible I suggest you try to upgrade to newer versions for more features (currently it's at version 4.0.2). Otherwise, if you cannot upgrade and the required feature is not available in MongoDB 3.0, it would have to be implemented inside your application.

Answer (score 0):

In this case $arrayElementAt returns only one element from a given position. If you want to manipulate a chunk of items you want to return you should use $slice. Please check the link for more references: [MongoDB $slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/)

```
{ $slice: 3 } //for the first 3
{ $slice: -3 } //for the last 3
{ $slice: 2, 3 } //for 3 elements after skiping the 2 frist
```

Comment: Both $arrayElementAt (not available in version 3.0) and $slice can be conceptually useful to solve my problem, the problem is that I can not use them in a $project clause in mongodb version 3.0

Comment: Yes. But the point is: If you know that already, why the question? Are you looking for a work-around?